# Does being able to protect a question that was deleted, and locked by the Community user make sense?

Tags: support, questions, locked-questions

On EL&U, I was able to protect [a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47224/im-very-sorry-for-what-ive-done) (the links is for 10k users) that was already deleted and locked by the Community user. Is this the expected behavior?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *wasn't* already Protected by Community. It was *Locked* by Community.

Since Protecting a locked - or deleted - or really, even closed - question is sorta pointless since none of them can be answered by *anyone*, I'd argue this is not so much *expected* as it is simply *ignored:* since setting or clearing the protected status means absolutely nothing in this context, it doesn't really matter whether or not you can or cannot set / clear it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the expected behavior?

I'd say [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). This is just a minor cosmetic issue and I think that it would just require more lines of unnecessary code.

Comment: Actually, I am not asking for any code change, nor am I reporting a bug. I am simply asking if that is the expected behavior; that's all.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I'd say yes, it is. I just wanted to make my answer more advanced

Comment: To say the truth, it has been made less accurate: It happens with all the questions deleted and blocked from the Community user; I am not sure that is classified as "it happens very rarely."

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Screw my bad English. I have meant that there are just a few members caring about this.